# Roots sage starter theme installation

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to install sage starter theme

```
composer create-project roots/sage your-theme-name 8.5.1
```

The theme is cloned but "dist" folder is missing. I installed bower and gulp. But still dist folder is missing from the file structure.

I get the following error while running gulp command.

events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Can somebody please point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
composer create-project roots/sage your-theme-name 8.5.1

npm install -g gulp bower
```

Navigate to the theme directory, then run npm install

```
bower install
```

now the bower_components directory is created

I had a permission error. Before running gulp change the permission.

```
sudo chmod 777 bower_components
sudo gulp
```

After completing this a dist folder is created and you are good to go.